# PHP Mail function do not sent mails

Tags: php, email, function

I have som html mail which I want to send via PHP Mail function,

so I have this:

```
$to = "mail@mail.sk";  
$from = "mail@mail.sk";   
$subject = "Some subject"  
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";   
$headers .= "From: $from" . "\r\n";   
$headers .= "Return-path: $from" . "\r\n";    
$headers .= "Bcc: $from\r\n";  
$message = "some html"; 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

But it always didnt send a mail, if i test it:

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {echo "Sent";}
else {echo "Didnt send";}
```

I always get Didnt send and no error message. What can be wrong ?

Comment: Would you be able to log the error that it gives out? It could have to do with the variables in your call or your SMTP server. Leaning more toward the former.

Comment: Is your server configured for sending mails?

Comment: Are you suing dedicated or shared server? Some providers blog mail sending

Comment: Are you trying it on localhost or online webserver ?

Comment: Is there a log on the mail server you can check?  Maybe it's refusing the message (in which case the code is working fine).

Comment: it's on online server, but i dont have rights to configure or view php.ini, so problem will be probably there ?

Comment: Is there even a mail server installed on the box?  Sendmail, Postfix, Exim4, something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Check your PHP error log. It might have more details as to what's failing. Usually an outright mail() fail is due to a misconfigured SMTP server setting, or lacking an SMTP server at all.

It can also fail if the SMTP server rejects the email, so check the SMTP server logs and see if it's complaining about something in your mail's setup.

Beyond that, don't use mail() for mime-formatted emails. Use something like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) to do it for you. They're far more reliable and provide MUCH better diagnostic error messages when something does blow up.

Answer (score 0):

- Check if all vars are filled. If so..
- Turn error and warning reporting on `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>`
- If nothing, check to see if your logs show any information.
- Test to see if the mail arrives on other adresses. For example a gmail account.
- If nothing check your server and SMTP settings.
- If that all fails, try [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) using an (external) SMTP.

Comment: Thank´s for advices! Problem was solved. Server block all mail() which have BCC.

Comment: If your serveradmin will not solve that, use swiftmailer with an external SMTP.